# how to create polling that doesn't consume memory through time?

Tags: flutter, dart, out-of-memory

I am trying to create long-time polling to an API that fetches data every five seconds to the app's home page, which sits in kiosk mode. Therefore, I added the following code:

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
   // code that polls for the active users from server
   final response = await http.get(_url);
   // rest of the code (which can be ignored)
});
```

This works great, but when I track the profile mode in flutter tools, I saw an increase in memory usage in time. and after a day or two, the app even crashes because of out-of-memory exceptions.
If there is any best practice to do this without memory crash or clearing I would appreciate that.

Thank you

Comment: That code looks fine. Are you sure it is the culprit? Aren't you storing the response in an internal data structure and never freeing it? (in a GC language it would be the most common way of having a memory leak)

Comment: Yes @estebarb, I was able to see the memory getting piled up in time. Even without using/storing the response. Basically, it seems like the HTTP call is not clearing its cache after any call.

Comment: A minimal, complete, reproducible example would help.  If there's a bug in the SDK or package, you would need to provide that anyway.